# Python strip every double quote from csv

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x, imacros

Hi I have a csv file that looks like the following.

```
"AB" ; "AA" ; "BA" ; "HI"
"CD" ; "BB" ; "BC" ; "JK"
"EF" ; "CC" ; "CE" ; "LM"
"GH" ; "DD" ; "DG" ; "MN"
```

How can I get the following code to strip off all the double quotes from every column in a csv file as for now it strips only the first column. Thanks

```
import csv

f = open("wakhawakha.csv", 'rt')
try:
    for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True):
        print('|'.join(row))
finally:
        f.close()
```

Comment: Also you should use `with` instead of `try: ... finally:` to open files.  The `with` operator does this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open it and read the string first.

```
import csv

with open("wakhawakha.csv", 'rt') as f:
    data = f.read()
new_data = data.replace('"', '')
for row in csv.reader(new_data.splitlines(), delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True):
    print ('|'.join(row))
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you wanted?

```
    for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter=';', skipinitialspace=True):
        print (''.join(row))
```

Comment: Some extra indentation could be used there.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new on StackOverflow and still getting used to the interface. :)

Comment: 'Tis fine. It appears @Michal K forgot some indentation there as well.

Comment: Thanks for the delimiter but unfortunately it still strips off only the first row.

Comment: Can you provide expected input with expected and actual output?

Comment: I've tried it locally and it strips everything. Is your indentation ok in your original file?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** I noticed you changed your indentation. The indentation in your OP was wrong:
Now it's fine:

```
f = open("wakhawakha.csv", 'rt')
try:
    for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True):
        print ('|'.join(row))
finally:
    f.close()
```

This way the output is this:

```
AB|;|AA|;|BA|;|HI
CD|;|BB|;|BC|;|JK
EF|;|CC|;|CE|;|LM
GH|;|DD|;|DG|;|MN
```

Is this the output you wanted? Or, did you just want to strip off all the double quotes? If so, then change this line in your code:

```
print ('|'.join(row))
```

to this:

```
print (' '.join(row))
```

Then you will get this output:

```
AB ; AA ; BA ; HI
CD ; BB ; BC ; JK
EF ; CC ; CE ; LM
GH ; DD ; DG ; MN
```