# Creating individual columns to write to new csv

Tags: python, csv

A CSV returns the following values

```
"1,323104,564382"
"2,322889,564483"
"3,322888,564479"
"4,322920,564425"
"5,322942,564349"
"6,322983,564253"
"7,322954,564154"
"8,322978,564121"
```

How would i take the " marks off each end of the rows, it seems to make individual columns when i do this.

```
reader=[[i[0].replace('\'','')] for i in reader]
```

does not change the file at all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python strip every double quote from csv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31281699/python-strip-every-double-quote-from-csv)

Answer (score 0):

It seems strictly easier to peel the quotes off first, and then feed it to the csv reader, which simply takes any iterable over lines as input.

```
import csv
import sys

f = open(sys.argv[1])
contents = f.read().replace('"', '')

reader = csv.reader(contents.splitlines())

for x,y,z in reader:
     print x,y,z
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming every line is wrapped by two double quotes, we can do this:

```
f = open("filename.csv", "r")
newlines = []
for line in f:  # we could use a list comprehension, but for simplicity, we won't.
    newlines.append(line[1:-1])
f.close()

f2 = open("filename.csv", "w")
for index, line in enumerate(f2):
    f2.write(newlines[index])
f2.close()
```

`[1:-1]` uses a list-indexing operation to get the second letter of the string to the last letter of the string, each represented by the indexes `1` and `-1`.

[`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.%E2%80%A6) is a helper function that turns an iterable into `(0, first_element), (1, second_element), ...` pairs.

Iterating over a file gets you its lines.